# aggregate count in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query to find the number of logins by a given user who has logged in more than once per day:

```
SELECT login_id, count(*) FROM login_test GROUP BY login_id HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

How can I get the `sum` of all the multiple logons? I've tried something like:

```
SELECT SUM(SELECT count(*) FROM login_test GROUP BY login_id HAVING count(*) > 1);
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a derived table:

```
SELECT sum(count)
FROM (
    SELECT login_id, count(*) 
    FROM login_test 
    GROUP BY login_id 
    HAVING count(*) > 1
    ) s;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select sum(t.cnt) as agg_count
   from
  (Select count(*) as cnt
         from table1
          Group by id having count(*) > 1
  ) t
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I generally do when I feel that there is something to explain, but I didn't think so in this case.